# Android Google MAPS API 2 JSON routes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, maps

I need to show routes in an activity
I have one activity and one Java file
Java file is used to get routes in form of json

So to use `AsyncTask` Should I call my method `getResponse()` from inside `doInBackground()` or paste contents of `getResponse()` in `doInBackground()`

`getResponse()` method is used to form string, make http request.

`getResponse()` have following parameters

```
LatLng srcPt
LatLng desPt
```

Also I need to send json object from java file to activity to draw routes